# Lost Referrer with New Google Analytics Account After Region Redirect in SPA with window.location.href

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, click-tracking, gtag.js

**Background:**

I have website which support 2 regions (US default region: mysite.com/contact; AU region: mysite.com/au/contact) which is built with NextJS + React SPA.

I have also 2 google analytics accounts for both regions separately, and using google gtag to send events. `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXX-REGION-A` and `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXX-REGION-B` after switch regions.

I also have internal code logic, where detect the geo location, and automatically redirect the client to the correct region. The way I did for redirect is set value `window.location.href` to refresh.

**Issue Steps:**

1. AU clients search on google;
2. google gives a link of mysite.com/contact （US link); and client clicks on the link
3. landed to the website mysite.com/contact, but the website automatically redirect to mysite.com/au/contact

What I can see is that, the referrer is lost after landed on mysite.com/au/contact, and in the google analytic dashboard, it shows it is "direct" source, meaning its traffic is from within the site (mysite.com/contact), but this is not right, it is actually from google organic search

**Note**

This issue does not happens on US region, when redirect does not happens, so I flag this issue only on the steps with AU region

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two viable things you could do to fix it.

One would be rewriting your redirect to something that would preserve the referrer. I would suggest moving the redirecting logic to backend and using your normal web-server redirections. Backend redirections preserve the original referrer in vast majority of cases. That also would be better for SEO, in conjunction with properly implemented hreflang metadata.

There's also a more hacky way of fixing it. Before redirecting the user, preserve their referrer in a cookie. When a user is redirected and before firing a new pageview to GA, you check if that cookie is set. If it's set, you force-fill the dr parameter of the GA payload (stands for document referrer) with what you have in the cookie, then you delete the cookie and send the pageview.

Keep an eye on your query parameters. A lot of paid sources attribution is done via query parameters of the request, so make sure your redirections, however done, preserve the query params.

Comment: Hi @BNazaruk, just checking the second way, instead of cookie if I simply retrieve the referrer from `document.referrer` and then just set `location.href` with xxxxxxxxxxxxx?dr=currentReferrer, would that automatically fix?

Comment: No, to my knowledge, the ga script doesn't take the dr query param from the request page and assume that's a referrer. You, on the other hand, could parse it out from the url, but I think it's best not to pollute the url.

Comment: Thank you. I think you gave me some light, and the query string may do the track, I am reading this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#dr

Comment: they mean the query string as a part of the payload of the request to the GA's endpoint. It has completely nothing to do with the query string on your site. And that's how I suggest you setting it in your tracking.

Comment: Thank you. Could I get some code example for this? I am using gtag.

Comment: make a separate question for that. Also, don't forget to show what you've tried setting. I suggest trying `dr` and `referrer`. I'm pretty sure it's possible to set with gtag, but overall, using gtag directly is a bad practice. Professionals use GTM for it. Here's how it's done in GTM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65882175/google-global-site-tag-how-to-override-page-referrer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71918025/how-to-override-referrer-in-google-analytics-after-refresh-from-window-location  I have also added this. For the `dr` and `referrer` it does not work in the query string from website. I am going to see if possible put in query string in https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=XXXXX?dr=www.google.com; see if that would create any better.

Comment: you really should start using the network tab and start understanding how GA collects data.

Comment: Ye, I have installed one plugin, shows params sending to GA. which seems does not working that way.